# What is tabularx doing with subfig in this example?

Tags: cross-referencing, tabularx, subfig

This is a simplified version of an environment that I use to hide a figure, showing only the caption.

One of the challenges was that I wanted to not only ignore `\includegraphics`, but ignore the whole table structure arranged around the individual figures. At the same time, labels and sublabels should still be accessible. Why is that difficult? Because this prints `??`, as `\phantom` does not make labels inside its argument accessible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Label}
    \phantom{\label{label}}
\end{figure}
\ref{label}
\end{document}
```

[Is there a version of `\phantom` that does not have that problem?]

This is how I worked around the problem, I thought. However, in this example, sublabels inside the `tabularx` are referred to as b, while a would be correct. (I combine this with `endfloat` and a couple of other packages, so it is hard to reproduce exactly the same with older versions of the code. The problem does appear in my big document when using `endfloat`, but not without. I am not sure how I managed to reduce it to this MWE without `endfloat`. Furthermore, the problem does not appear with `tabular` or `tabular*`, and I happened to switch from one to the other between revisions of the manuscript.)

So, in short: what is going wrong when using `tabularx`?

Receiving warnings about multiply-defined labels (the `aux` file confirms that), I suspect that with tabularx, the input somehow gets processed twice. Upon further debugging, it seems that `\envlabels` is only set once (that is, `\g@addto@macro` is only executed once), and only executed once; but it has its contents duplicated: check with

```
        \renewcommand{\label}[1]{
            \typeout{This is printed once.}
            \g@addto@macro\envlabels{
                \typeout{But this is printed twice.}
                \orgsubfloat{\label{####1}}}}
```

and

```
macro:->\orgsubfloat {\label {subfloat}}\orgsubfloat {\label{subfloat}}
```

How can that happen?

This is my (much reduced) code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newenviron}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\makeatletter
\newenviron{hidecontent}{
    \gdef\envlabels{}
    \let\orgsubfloat=\subfloat
    \renewcommand{\subfloat}[2][]{
        \renewcommand{\label}[1]{
            \g@addto@macro\envlabels{\orgsubfloat{\label{####1}}}}
        ##2}
    \begin{figure}
        \phantom{\envbody}
        \envlabels
    \end{figure}}{}

\begin{document}
Subfloat \subref{subfloat} is wrong, it should be (a).
\begin{hidecontent}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l}
        \subfloat{\label{subfloat}}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{hidecontent}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ad Problem 1: `\label`s occurring inside `\phantom`  aren't accessible**

The reason why `\label`s placed inside `\phantom`s aren't accessible is:

The `\label` command does trigger writing information to the auxiliary files.
`\protected@write` is used for this.
`\protected@write` does trigger writing things not in `\immediate` fashion but in delayed fashion. This means: Things do not get written immediately when the writing-directive is encountered but things get written at the time when the box during whose construction the `\write`-command in question occurred is processed and shipped out/written to .pdf-file/.dvi-file due to the output-routine. (Things are done this way for a good reason: E.g. often page numbers aren't known at the time of constructing boxes but they are known at the time when the output-routine prepares a page for `\shipout`. Things like `\label` also write page numbers to auxiliary files so you can do `\pageref`-references in consecutive latex runs/when compiling the document again.)

With `\phantom` everything is placed inside a box which never gets shipped
out as it is used only for measuring and then creating another empty box
of same measurements.

Thus an approach could be redefining `\protected@write` to add its own
call to the definition of some macro and to call that macro
outside `\phantom`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\phantomWithDelayedWrites[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \gdef\CollectedCallsToProtected@write{}%
  \long\def\protected@write##1##2##3{%
    \g@addto@macro\CollectedCallsToProtected@write{\protected@write{##1}{##2}{##3}}%
  }%
  \phantom{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\CollectedCallsToProtected@write
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{9}

\begin{figure}
    \caption{Label}%

    A\phantomWithDelayedWrites{ Text Text \label{label} Text Text \stepcounter{mycounter}}B%

    A Text Text  Text Text B%
\end{figure}

Reference to figure 1 even while the correesponding \verb|\label|-command occured
inside \verb|phantom|: \ref{label}

By the way: Did you realize that counters etc get stepped inside \verb|\phantom|?
If this was not the case, then \verb|mycounter| would still have the value \verb|9|
but it has value {\csname verbatim@font\endcsname\selectfont\themycounter}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way:

You may encounter problems with things that place `\specials` and/or named destinations for hyperlinks and the like into the resulting output-file. E.g., when using the [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)-package, destinations for hyperlinks will not end up in the .pdf-file if directives for placing them occurred within `\phantom`.
When using [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), then sectioning commands like `\caption` or `\section` trigger the placing of such `\specials`/destinations...

I think a feature not based on placing empty boxes of equal measurement but based on completely colorless and thus invisible text (probably with the property of not being copy-paste-able) in the resulting .pdf-output-file would be nice:

If up-to-date software is available and if your goal is to produce a pdf-file, you can probably avoid fiddling around with `\phantom` and the related problems by making things completely transparent and thus invisible by means of Heiko Oberdiek's [`transparent`](https://ctan.org/pkg/transparent) package.
When doing things with the  [`transparent`](https://ctan.org/pkg/transparent) package, the document in question needs to be compiled twice at least. Warning-messages on the terminal or in the .log-file will inform you about this.

If you also wish to prevent copy-pasting of invisible text, you can probably use Heiko Oberdiek's [`accsupp`](https://ctan.org/pkg/accsupp) package for providing alternative text which will be delivered as a result of copy-pasting.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{accsupp}[2007/11/14]
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\parindent=0ex
\parskip=.66\baselineskip

\begin{document}

\textbf{Here inside the {\csname verbatim@font\endcsname\string\fbox} the
``non-phan\-to\-mi\-zed'' thing:}

Here the start:
\fbox{%
  \parbox{4cm}{%
    Some text. When you try to copy-paste, with the ``non-phan\-to\-mi\-zed'' thing the
    pas\-ting-re\-sult may be nice and with the ``phantomized'' thing the pas\-ting-re\-sult 
    may be the advice not to do this.\\
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}%
  }%
}
Here the end.

\textbf{Here inside the {\csname verbatim@font\endcsname\string\fbox} the
``phantomized'' thing:}

Here the start: %
\fbox{%
  \begingroup 
  % Make the text inside the group transparent and thus invisible within the pdf-viewer:
  \transparent{0.0}%
  % Within AccSupp provide replacement-text when attempting to copy-paste the material:
  \BeginAccSupp{method=pdfstringdef, space, unicode, ActualText={DO NOT COPY-PASTE THIS!}}%
  %
  \parbox{4cm}{%
    Some text. When you try to copy-paste, with the ``non-phan\-to\-mi\-zed'' thing the
    pas\-ting-re\-sult may be nice and with the ``phantomized'' thing the pas\-ting-re\-sult 
    may be the advice not to do this.\\
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}%
  }%
  %
  \EndAccSupp{}%
  \endgroup
}
Here the end.

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Ad Problem 2: multiply defined labels when collecting calls to `\label` within a macro within a `tabularx`**

For adjusting widths of cells `tabularx` does several test runs during which tokens that form content of table-cells get carried out.
Thus within `tabularx` your `\g@addto@macro`-directives also get carried out several times.
You need to ensure that your `\g@addto@macro`-directive gets carried out only in the final run, not during test runs.

How to do that? :

In test runs `\@footnotetext` is let equal to `\TX@trial@ftn` (see 
*The tabularx package, David Carlisle, 2016/02/03*, 
⟨http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf⟩, section 5 The macros, code line 119), thus you can write a macro that tests on test-runs by checking the definition of `\@footnotetext`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newenviron}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\DoIfNotTabularxTestRun{%
  \ifx\@footnotetext\TX@trial@ftn\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{subfig}

\makeatletter
\newenviron{hidecontent}{%
  \gdef\envlabels{}%
  \let\orgsubfloat=\subfloat
  \renewcommand{\subfloat}[2][]{%
    \begingroup %<-tabularx is a restricting scope on its own.
                %  but you may need this scope when using hidecontent's subfloat
                % without additional environments. Otherise \subfloat's redefinition
                % will remain effective even at the time of carrying out \envlabels
    \renewcommand{\label}[1]{%
      \DoIfNotTabularxTestRun{\myg@addto@macro\envlabels{\orgsubfloat{\protect\label{####1}}}}%
    }%
    ##2%
   \endgroup
  }%
  \begin{figure}%
    \phantom{\envbody}%
    \envlabels
  \end{figure}%
}{}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Subfloat \subref{subfloat} should be (a). Is it?
\begin{hidecontent}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l}
        \subfloat{\label{subfloat}}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{hidecontent}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks!

Comment: I just added some remarks about "hiding" things without using `\phantom`, just making text transparent and non-copy-paste-able. (People might try to "blindly" mark/select invisible text for copy-pasting into a text file where things turn out visible...) Another approach at preventing copy-paste might be a font with some  cloned font-encoding and a [cmap](https://ctan.org/pkg/cmap) for that cloned font-encoding which does map all things of the cloned font-encoding., e.g., to spaces or the null-byte-character or whatever...