# How can I add a single curly brace to a macro?

Tags: macros, braces

I am trying to compose `\textit{abc}` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\def\test{}

\catcode123=12 % change cat code of "{" to "other"
\g@addto@macro\test{
\catcode123=1  % restore the cat code

\g@addto@macro\test{abc}

\catcode125=12 % change cat code of "}" to "other"
\g@addto@macro\test}
\catcode125=2  % restore the cat code

\begin{document}
    \test
\end{document}
```

However, issuing `\test` does not print an italic `abc`. How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: You need to give an initial (empty) definition to `\test`: `\def\test{}`. You are probably getting an `Undefined control sequence` error, right?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Sorry, that was just an error of my MWE that's fixed now. The error is that the output shows `abc"`, *non-italic*.

Comment: You can't (terms and conditions may apply) add a single catcode 1 (or 2) curly brace to a macro. The curly braces you add are catcode 12, so they don't work as argument delimiters for `\textit`. You can resort to a brace trick (like in the answer siracusa just posted) or add the pair at once.

Comment: @UlrichDiez it looks good certainly! I haven't tested it, though. I'm note sure it works when `\test` is not initialized to be empty, as well.

Comment: What about
`\newcommand\globaladdbraces[1]{\expandafter\gdef\expandafter#1\expandafter{\expandafter{#1}}} ... \def\test{} ... \g@addto@macro\test{abc} ... \globaladdbraces\test ... \show\test ... \expandafter\textit\test` ?

Comment: Yes. `\test` must be initialized to empty. I deleted my comment and corrected this. ;-) I suppose your exploration of the limits of the concept of successively composing things via `\g@addto@macro` is not just a moot thing for the sake of having fun while playing around with (La)TeX but is an aspect of approaching a concrete task/of solving a concrete problem. Perhaps help can be improved when you reveal as many details of that task/problem as possible. ;-)

Comment: By the way: In the very first line of your question you say you wish to compose `\textit....`  but in the example provided by you the sequence `\textit` does not occur at all. So my question is: Do you wish to successively compose the entire `\textit{abc}`-command, i.e., the token-sequence `\textit`, `{`, `a`, `b`, `c`, `}`  or do you already have a sequence of tokens and the problem is just about passing that sequence as argument to `\textit` ?

Comment: @UlrichDiez my use case (very briefly): create an environment that shows a only caption. Render `\envbody` invisible, but patch commands (`\subfloat`, `\label` etc) to store their arguments somewhere, ensuring correct nesting. Some more general info here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506424. My specific questions revolves around the need to properly account for \subfloat{\label{a}\label{b}\label{c}...} - doesn't make sense, but someone might do it. (Except for that `tabularx` problem that I circumvent by `tabular*`, I do have a solution now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following patterns to build your macro's replacement text. The basic idea is to not build the final result directly but to first create a sequence of commands that yields the final result when it is fully expanded in an `\edef`. For building the sequence you can use the `\g@addto@macro` macro, adding material as your algorithm goes.

Here are the sequence patterns to be added for various aspects (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10371/23765) for an explanation of the brace patterns):

- Add a macro name: `\noexpand\macroname`
- Add general material that should occur unexpanded: `\unexpanded{...}`
- Add a left brace: `{\iffalse}\fi`
- Add a right brace: `\iffalse{\fi}`
- All unexpandable material or `\protect`'ed macros can be used directly

From those pattern we can build the macro mentioned in your question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter

\def\test{}

\g@addto@macro\test{\noexpand\textit}
\g@addto@macro\test{{\iffalse}\fi}
\g@addto@macro\test{abc}
\g@addto@macro\test{\iffalse{\fi}}

%\show\test
\edef\test{\test}
%\show\test

\begin{document}
    \test
\end{document}
```

If you uncomment the `\show` calls in this example, you can see the macro definition before

```
> \test=macro:
->\noexpand \textit {\iffalse }\fi abc\iffalse {\fi }.
```

and after the expansion

```
> \test=macro:
->\textit {abc}.
```

Comment: Perhaps `\g@addto@macro\test{\unexpanded{abc}}`, just to be on the safe side

Comment: That's a neat trick!

Answer (score 5):

Although `expl3`'s regex engine (which is loaded by `regexpatch`) is an excellent tool (and my job description is to merchandise `expl3`), in this case it's like using a shotgun to kill a fly :-)

You can achieve the same effect using a macro to define another. A simplistic definition of a `\MakeItalic` macro would be `\def\MakeItalic#1{\edef#1{\noexpand\textit{#1}}}`. The `\noexpand` would make sure that `\textit` doesn't blow up inside the `\edef` (you could omit the `\noexpand` if you used `\protected@edef` instead). The `#1` would be your macro that *contains* `abc`, which would expand into `abc`.

A more robust definition of `\MakeItalic` would require e-TeX (you're using LaTeX, so that is the default anyway):

```
\newcommand{\MakeItalic}[1]{%
  \edef#1{\noexpand\textit{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}}
```

The difference from the previous version is that instead of completely expanding `#1`, we expand it only once with `\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}`. This makes sure that if your `\test` macro contains other macros or active characters it won't explode.

A test document:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\MakeItalic}[1]{%
  \edef#1{\noexpand\textit{\unexpanded\expandafter{#1}}}}
% Complicated definition of \test
\def\test{abc}
% Add \textit{...}
\MakeItalic\test
\begin{document}
\texttt{\meaning\test} = \test
\end{document}
```

produces:

> [image]

Comment: I like this answer, and I have learnt a lot. I have accepted the other answer though, as it is closer to what I have been asking.

Comment: @bers No worries :-) Indeed, with siracusa's answer you can compose the token list sort of step-by-step, whereas my approach puts everything in place with one blow.

Answer (score 0):

One answer could look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\def\test{abc}
\regexpatchcmd{\test}{.*}{\c{textit}\cB\{\0\cE\}}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \test
\end{document}
```

A variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\makeatletter

\def\test{\textit XXX}
\g@addto@macro\test{abc}
\g@addto@macro\test{XXX}

\regexpatchcmd{\test}{XXX(.*)XXX}{\cB\{\1\cE\}}{}{}

\begin{document}
    \test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, you just want "italic abc", not "italic {abc}". Then why not simply `\def\test{\textit{abc}}`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I want to compose \test programmatically, like in a loop that has `a`, `b`, `c` (which are commands that are more complex than that, of course).

Comment: Then why not `\def\deftest#1#2{\def#1{\textit{#2}}}` and then `\deftest\test{abd}`? Sorry to be such a pain, but I think you are over-complicating something rather simple :-)