# Why does this regexpatch command only work once, not twice?

Tags: patching, l3regex

Based on an early version of [How can I add a single curly brace to a macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506613), I have tried the following to add, one by one, inner commands to some outer command. (The reason I am doing this is that I do not know when the last element has been reached, to every step of the sequence must be valid code.) But while the first replacement works, the second does not, and I don't really see a difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\newcommand{\addinnertoouter}[1]{
    \regexpatchcmd{\test}
    { \c{outer} \{ (.*) \} \Z}
    { \c{outer} \cB\{ \1 \c{inner} \cB\{ #1 \cE\} \cE\} }
    {}{error}
}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\def\test{\outer{\inner{abc}}}
\meaning\test

\addinnertoouter{def}
\meaning\test

\addinnertoouter{ghi}
\meaning\test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know about `\tl_build_...` described in `interface3`?

Comment: @egreg I did not, thanks! One problem that I have is that I don't know when the sequence will be finished, so calling the required `tl_build_end` command will be difficult. (I might be able to do it before using the command.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `l3regex` directly instead of `\regexpatchcmd` it works:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \addinnertoouter { m }
  {
    \regex_replace_once:nnNTF
      { \c{outercmd} \{ (.*) \} \Z}
      { \c{outercmd} \cB\{ \1 \c{inner} \cB\{ #1 \cE\} \cE\} }
      \test
      { }
      { error }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\def\test{\outercmd{\inner{abc}}}
\meaning\test

\addinnertoouter{def}
\meaning\test

\addinnertoouter{ghi}
\meaning\test
\end{document}
```

> [image]

(`\outer` is a (very special) TeX primitive, so it's better if you use something else.)

The issue is that `l3regex` apparently makes the added `def` tokens catcode 12 (looks like a bug to me; I'll summon a wizard to check), and when `\regexpatchcmd` tries to retokenize them they become catcode 11, and `\regexpatchcmd` thinks (correctly) that the macro cannot be patched. If you don't mind that the inserted tokens be catcode 12 (in this case it probably won't matter), then `\regex_replace_once:nnNTF` will suit your needs.

---

Beware that the argument of your `\addinnertoouter` is still a regular expression, so if you do `\addinnertoouter{\textit{jkl}}` the output will not be what you expect. You can use the `\u` feature of `l3regex` to add an arbitrary token list (without catcode changes, so it will also work with `\regexpatchcmd`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_bers_tmpa_tl
\NewDocumentCommand \addinnertoouter { m }
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_bers_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \regexpatchcmd
      \test
      { \c{outercmd} \{ (.*) \} \Z}
      { \c{outercmd} \cB\{ \1 \c{inner} \cB\{ \u{l_bers_tmpa_tl} \cE\} \cE\} }
      { }
      { error }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\def\test{\outercmd{\inner{abc}}}
\meaning\test

\addinnertoouter{def}
\meaning\test

\addinnertoouter{ghi}
\meaning\test

\addinnertoouter{\textit{jkl}}
\meaning\test
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

Phelype Oleinik [already described](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506624/23765) the problem with catcode changes in `\regexpatchcmd`, so I'm skipping the explanation part here ... The problem can also be fixed by replacing the line

```
{ \c{outer} \cB\{ \1 \c{inner} \cB\{ #1 \cE\} \cE\} }
```

by

```
{ \c{outer} \cB\{ \1 \c{inner} \cB\{ \cL(#1) \cE\} \cE\} }
```

in your original code, correctly giving

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! Again, this is exactly what I need. Still, I have accepted the other answer as it was earlier, gives an explanation and a working solution. I do like the elegance of this answer, though - `\cL` is basically what I have been looking for. For all others searching, that stuff is explained in the `l3regex` package documentation.

Comment: Hmmm - this stops working when I replace `def` by `d1f`, probably because `\cL` means "letters". Is there a more general catcode that I could use?

Comment: @bers `\cL d\cO 1\cL f` will do; `\cO` in front of `1` is redundant, because digits have category code 12 by default, but clarity might be preferable.

Comment: @egreg I see. But that requires knowing what the parameters are - I get these from a different macro. What I did now is change the catcode of the digits.

Comment: @bers You can do `\def\temp{<the tokens>}` and use `\u{temp}` for the replacement text. This will keep the original category codes.

Comment: @bers My answer only works for letter characters. The only general solution I can see is the one using the `\u` command as described by the other answers, because the regex replacement text must produce exactly the same catcodes for each token as active for the current catcode regime.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\u` feature of `l3regex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\newcommand{\addinnertoouter}[1]{%
  \def\berstemp{#1}%
  \regexpatchcmd{\test}
    { \c{outer} \{ (.*) \} \Z}
    { \c{outer} \cB\{ \1 \c{inner} \cB\{ \u{berstemp} \cE\} \cE\} }
    {}{error}
}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\def\test{\outer{\inner{abc}}}
\meaning\test

\addinnertoouter{def}
\meaning\test

\addinnertoouter{ghi}
\meaning\test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's the trick! I had tried `\u{#1}`...